# Getting currently playing song from spotify with libspotify

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I'm trying to make an application for windows that gets the current playing song on spotify. I have succeeded in doing this by just reading mainwindowtitle from the process and cutting off the first 10 letters on that string, but I want to see if this is possible by using the libspotify API?
I have searched around and from what I see, most of the questions loops back to using html and facebook verification or is a question related to android/Ios.

So my questions would be: Can I use libspotify to get currently playing song on spotify and information about this (Like location in song, how long that song is, what album and albumart, etc... or the spotify URI so I can use the metadata API as well to get the other information), and is there examples for me to follow that does something similar? From what I have seen the examples that spotify delivers on the libspotify API is just on creating standalone streamers... 
I could not find a question like so on my searches, but Im sorry if this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, libspotify does not provide remote control or access to the Spotify desktop client. It's for writing a standalone client using the Spotify service.

If the user is scrobbling from Spotify to Last.fm, you may be able to use the Last.fm API to find out what they're listening to.